# How do I bind a Ribbon control to my ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, ribbon, caliburn.micro

I've been struggling since yesterday to build a (what I thought) simple Ribbon on WPF, using MVVM.
I found quite a few links on the internet (and on Stack Overflow), but none could really solve my problem.

In a nutshell my question is: **Am I doing it wrong, or is it just plain impossible to bind a Ribbon to a ViewModel like I'm doing?**

### In Details:

This is my model for the menu: Each *MenuGroup* should be rendered as a *RibbonGroup*, and *MenuGroup* contains a collection of *MenuItem* which should be rendered as a *RibbonButton* (inside their respective *RibbonGroup* of course).

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace MyCompany.Poc.Wpf.Models
{
    public class MenuGroup
    {
        public MenuGroup()
        {
            Items = new BindableCollection<MenuItem>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
}


using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyCompany.Poc.Wpf.Models
{
    public class MenuItem
    {
        public MenuGroup Group { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Link { get; set; }

        public ICommand OpenMenuUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel just contains a collection of those MenuGroup, for the binding on the XAML:

```
public IObservableCollection<MenuGroup> LegacyMenuItems
{
    get { return _legacyMenuItems; }
}
```

The collection is populated (for the time being) as soon as the VM is instanciated, with fake data):

```
var group1 = new MenuGroup();
group1.Name = "Group 1";
var group2 = new MenuGroup();
group2.Name = "Group 2";

group1.Items.Add(new MenuItem {Group = group1, Link = "http://www.google.co.uk", Name = "Link 1", OpenMenuUrl = OpenMenuUrl});
group1.Items.Add(new MenuItem {Group = group1, Link = "http://www.google.co.uk", Name = "Link 2", OpenMenuUrl = OpenMenuUrl});
group2.Items.Add(new MenuItem {Group = group2, Link = "http://www.google.co.uk", Name = "Link 3", OpenMenuUrl = OpenMenuUrl});
group2.Items.Add(new MenuItem {Group = group2, Link = "http://www.google.co.uk", Name = "Link 4", OpenMenuUrl = OpenMenuUrl});

LegacyMenuItems.Add(group1);
LegacyMenuItems.Add(group2);
```

Now the XAML:

```
<my:Ribbon  DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <my:RibbonTab Header="Legacy A.I." ItemsSource="{Binding LegacyMenuItems}">
        <my:RibbonTab.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <my:RibbonGroup Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <my:RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <my:RibbonButton Label="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding OpenMenuUrl}" CommandParameter="{Binding Link}"></my:RibbonButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
                </my:RibbonGroup>
            </DataTemplate>
        </my:RibbonTab.ItemTemplate>
    </my:RibbonTab>

    <my:RibbonTab Header="Static">
        <my:RibbonGroup Name="Administration" Header="Admin">
            <my:RibbonButton Label="Stuffs" Command="{Binding Path=OpenMenuUrl}" CommandParameter="http://www.mycompany.com/somelink"></my:RibbonButton>
            <my:RibbonButton Label="Google" Command="{Binding Path=OpenMenuUrl}" CommandParameter="http://www.google.co.uk"></my:RibbonButton>
        </my:RibbonGroup>
    </my:RibbonTab>

</my:Ribbon>
```

And what it renders:
[image: Doesn't look right, does it...]
[image: Statically loaded, works like a charm...]

As you can see, the "Static" tab works well and the "title" for the ribbon group ("Admin") is displayed at the right place.

Now, the "Legacy A.I." tab, **has no buttons** (there should be 2 buttons in each group), and the RibbonGroup titles are displayed funny (**below where they should be**).

If you have any clue on what I'm doing wrong here, please tell me :)
I'm very new on the WPF world, so I obviously don't understand templating properly...

A few facts to help you make a call:
- The Model is loaded correctly, since we can see "Group 1" and "Group 2" which are part of the fake data loaded in the ViewModel
- I tried Telerik's RadRibbon and it behaves exactly the same! So unless they are BOTH wrong at the same place, the problem must comes from me

Good night and good luck :)

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: @Will: looking forward to seeing your answer then.

Comment: @Den: Sorry, I'm not able to answer as much as I used to.  I have to spend what little time I have dealing with flags, you know.  If you're wondering why posting full solutions on other sites is discouraged, I suggest you ask about it on [meta].

Answer (score 1):

I am using the ribbon also in a MVVM application and decided to stick with controls defined in XAML linking them to static ICommand properties in classes defined in my viewmodel layer. This is very inflexible but works for me so far.

If you have downloaded and installed the official Microsoft Ribbon you will find it's source and some sample's in:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Ribbon for
>   WPF\MicrosoftRibbonForWPFSourceAndSamples

This includes a sample that also implements MVVM. This uses a totally different method though an may not be what you need, but I think it may be helpful to look it over.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday and struggled a lot to find a solution.

I think your problem could be solved with a **HierarchicalDataTemplate**.

```
<r:Ribbon>
    <r:RibbonTab Header="Legacy A.I." ItemsSource="{Binding LegacyMenuItems}">
        <r:RibbonTab.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding LegacyMenuItems}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType      = "{x:Type r:RibbonGroup}"
                                                  ItemsSource   = "{Binding Items}" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </r:RibbonTab.Style>
    </r:RibbonTab>
</r:Ribbon>
```

Comment: You could give some references about the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

Comment: `HierarchicalDataTemplate` are quite common in WPF but it is not obvious when to use them which is why I answered the question in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Captain Necroposter here:

I had the same rendering issue and this is my solution

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type navigation:RibbonTabViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type navigation:RibbonGroupViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" ></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type navigation:RibbonButtonViewModel}">
                <RibbonButton Label="{Binding Path=Title}" Command="{Binding Path=ClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"></RibbonButton>
            </DataTemplate>
```

To begin with i had a RibbonGroup as template content for my RibbonGroupViewModel. Thanks to latest VS i was able to inspect the live tree and find the issue there.